# How do I set a lower min API level in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play

I want to publish my own android game in google play and its my first time trying it with unity I have a background publishing a game with android studio.

I created a new version in the google play console, and inserted the App Bundle and all the pics and the info needed. I sent it for google play to check, and after a few days google approved the version. But when I wanted to downloaded the app from my phone it says: "your device is not compatible with that version". I looked a bit on the intenet, and I think that the problem is that the min API level is too high; 19. With that, I haven't find anyone that showed how to lower it.[19 is the lowest API level here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfVMP.png)

The app targeted SDK level is 30 (android 11), as google play asked.

Can someone help me with that? Or if you have any other idea how to fix this problem, pleas write it down here.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

API Level **18** is from [**July 9, 2012**](https://www.javatpoint.com/android-versions) .... I think after over 9 years you can kind of stop the support ;)

And that is [exactly what hapened](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2021/07/google-play-services-discontinuing-jelly-bean.html)

---

From [Meet Google Play's target API level requirement](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk)

> New apps and app updates must target Android 10 (API level 29) or higher

and

> Starting in **August 2021**, **new apps** will need to:
>
> - Target API level 30 (Android 11) or above and adjust for behavioral changes;

and

> Starting in **November 2021**, **app updates** will be required to target API level 30 or above and adjust for behavioral changes in Android 11.

so you definitely have to target `API level 30` except your app already existed and it is only an update. Then it still needs to be at least `29`.

The min version can / is recommended to be kept at the lowest that your app supports (depends on your implementations etc). So if your app supports API level 19 you should keep this as the minimum version.

---

However, the error sounds more like your test device is using some older API level Android and you should probably use a newer one.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try and get an answer back as soon as possible.

Comment: OK look: I tried a couple of times, with the first try targeted SDK 30 and min API 29, and with the second try targeted SDK 30 and min API 30. However, it seems like as higher the min API as little devices can run that version. My device is Xiaomi note 10. Here are some numbers:

min API 19: 2,912 supported devices.

min API 29: 1,297 supported devices.

min API 30: 295 supported devices.


my other game is min API 16, and it works perfectly. Is there a wat to make the new version for this game also min API 16?